# Самомодификация

Tags: php

Реально ли сделать так, чтобы php-скрипт мог сам себя модифицировать, добавляя строки в самого себя? Например, через время он добавит в себя "**echo "Час прошел";**"

Comment: Вопрос некорректен или я не так понял? Под "модификацией скрипта" вы имеете ввиду модификацию клиенского HTML из PHP?

Comment: Совершенно реально. file_put_contents() и file_get_contents() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php и все что хотите меняйте в файле.

Comment: @AGS17 Вопрос вполне корректен. Скрипт на php может открыть свой исходник и модифицировать его, Только зачем - не ясно

Comment: @Darth так я не спорю. Я и хотел уточнить у автора, он это подразумевал, либо ему требовалось просто что-то дополнительно отображать у клиента после того, как "Час прошел"

Comment: Реально. Но смысла не имеет.

Comment: @Darth вспомнилось, как под БК писали самомодифицирующийся код на ассемблере, так как иначе в память не влезал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь это вам надо из спортивного интереса.

```
$f = fopen(__FILE__, "a");
fwrite($f, "echo 'Прошел час';".PHP_EOL); 
fclose($f);
```